# Is Extrude or Boolean the better method?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, extrude, boolean-modifier

When trying to create a game-ready-asset with a handle like an axe or a hammer, is it better to extrude the handle from the object so that it remains as a whole, or is it better to create the handle separately and then connect it with boolean or other methods?

Below left is an extruded handle, on the right a boolean after a subdivision modifier.

[image: Extrude(left) vs Boolean(right)]

With Boolean you have more control over the original object to create the head of the axe / hammer and can apply the join later.

Would it even be worth considering keeping the two as separate objects and exporting them as they are?

When extruding you have the flow of the mesh, you can see the lines of the mesh go together and it feels like one object and not two pushed together. I would like to know what you prefer or what you think is a better practice.

Comment: Hello how does the object you'retrying to achieve look like?

Comment: I think your first decision is: Do you _need_ the object to be a continuous, manifold surface? In general, model separate parts _as_  separate parts, unless animated deformation, printing, or some other constraint says no. Most often, non-deforming objects only need to be good to look at.